# Issue displaying map highcharter shiny

Tags: javascript, r, highcharts, shiny, r-highcharter

I met some problems in displaying a map in a shiny using the package highcharter.
When I try to display it in my RStudio Viewer, all is ok, my map is fine.

Whereas, when I try to display it in my shiny app via the functions `highchartOutput`(in the server) and `renderHighchart`(in the ui).

The "highcharter code" of my map in pretty simple, and it's not the problem because I can display it in my viewer, but I show it anyway here :

```
  carte <- highchart(type = "map") %>%
    hc_title(text = "Test") %>%
    hc_add_series_map(Map,as.data.frame(Dat),value='N',joinBy=c('name','LIB_DEP'))%>%
    hc_mapNavigation( enableMouseWheelZoom=T) -> carte

  carte
```

I bet the problem comes from the .js libraries I load, but not sure about it.

Anyone could help me ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you put a _reproducible minimal_ example? If we cannont reproduce the problem we cannot detect how is wrong.

Comment: @jbkunst thank you for your answer. It would be awful to post all my code here, and without the data you can not simply launch it and wait for errors.
But I will do my best to be clear. Basically this, http://www.highcharts.com/blog/post/223-visualizing-the-gender-of-us-senators/, was my pattern. I used this code, I took my map (french territory) and my data. I can display an highmap in my RStudio Viewer, all works very well.

My issue : my map doesn't display in my shiny.
I guess there is a problem of .js code sourcing.
What is the "standard method" to display an highmap in a shiny?

Comment: You're right :  don't post your whole code! Just make a small example so we can reproduce your issue by just copy/pasting and without having to think/guess too much. If files are needed that can't be replaced by fake data or data included in a package, post them on dropbox.

Comment: @HubertL SERVER
    output$carte_dep <- renderHighchart({
    Map <- "www/Contours_geo/fr-all-all.geo.json" %>%
      jsonlite::fromJSON(simplifyVector = FALSE)
    carte <- highchart(type = "map") %>%
      hc_title(text = "Test") %>%
      hc_add_series_map(Map,as.data.frame(Dat),value='N',joinBy=c('name','LIB_DEP'))%>%
      hc_mapNavigation( enableMouseWheelZoom=T) -> carte
    
    carte
    
    })

UI
    box(width = 12,status = "primary"
                               ,highchartOutput("carte_dep")
                              )

This is a simple version.

Comment: This is a simple version that is NOT working : please include all `library()` and make sure the code works when copied/pasted in a new environment

Comment: I think I found the issue. This is a problem of compatibilty between RCharts and Highcharter, I think it's not so simple to use both packages in the same shiny app

Comment: Yep, surely `rCharts` load other version (possibily an old one) that `highcharter` is loading.

Comment: Yes...too bad that the newest package (I think it's highcharter, not sure of it) is not aligned with the oldest one. I guess there is also competition in R packages....Anyway. Thanks for your help